# Sort object-array and additionally a nested array in these objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**Updated example, as it didn't match to the object structure which was given in the post**

There is an array, which has multiple objects like this:

```
{ 
    text: text,
    elements: [
        { 
            id: id, 
            page: pageNumber 
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to sort the content in two ways:

1. Sort all array elements by the `text`-field

I would do like this:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
    if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

2. The content of the nested `elements`-array should also be sorted by the `page`-field.

I don't know how to sort an array, which is nested in the objects... Unfortunately it gets more difficult as the elements are strings, but represent some page numbers. So how can I sort these data in a correct way, as elements could look like `123` or `23-34`? And in the case `123-125`, `23-34`, the last element should be the first.

**Example**

```
[
    {   
        text: 'Some text',
        elements: [
            { id: 1, pages: '45-67' },
            { id: 2, pages: '12-34' }
        ]

    },
    {
        text: 'Another text',
        elements: [
            { id: 3, pages: '12-34' }
        ]
    }
]
```

Should be sorted to:

```
[
    {
        text: 'Another text',
        elements: [
            { id: 3, pages: '12-34' }
        ]
    },
    {   
        text: 'Some text',
        elements: [
            { id: 2, pages: '12-34' },
            { id: 1, pages: '45-67' }
        ]

    },
]
```

So the object order has changed, as **A** is before **S** and the order of the page elements in the (now) second object are ordered the other way round.

Comment: What if you sort it by the nested elements first and then sort it again by the text? That way you'd have it sorted as you want (event though it's not efficient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, you could use the power of [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). And use for the page array another sort function with splitting the string.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, text: 'Some text', elements: [{ id: 1, pages: '45-67' }, { id: 2, pages: '12-34' }, { id: 4, pages: '12-5' }, { id: 5, pages: '12' }] }, { id: 3, text: 'Another text', elements: [{ id: 3, pages: '12-34' }] }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
});

array.forEach(function (el) {
    el.elements.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aa = a.pages.split('-'),
            bb = b.pages.split('-');
        return aa[0] - bb[0] || (aa[1] || 0) - (bb[1] || 0);
    });
});
    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Oh, I did a big mistake. My example structure is not the same as shown in the beginning of the post. I'm very sorry for that. 'elements' should be sorted by 'page', while elements is an array, and page just an object-string.

Comment: I'm really very sorry. I updated the post. Please look at the example.

Comment: What is the advantage of 'localCompare' instead of using 'sort' - like Samuel shown in his answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not a difficult one, as the author has already broken down the problem into smaller chunks. For instance - you mentioned sort the text first and then the nested property (pages), which you are having trouble with.

Your use case is easier as we know you are dealing with pages, so the page numbers will be consistent. E.g. It is unlikely to have entry like '10-20' and '10-15', well if they do then my code below will have to expand a bit to handle this sort of situation.

Otherwise what I have done below is to split the string entry using the `-` character as delimeter to get a `fromPage` and `toPage` parameter. Then using the fromPage we do the usual compare in the `sort` function to determine who is smaller.

Once that is sorted, then I sort the outer items which you already got a solution for it.

**Solution:**

```
// Sort the nested properties first - in this instance it will be page
example.forEach(item => {
  item.pages.sort(function (a, b) {
    aFromPage = a.split('-')[0];
    bFromPage = b.split('-')[0];
    // Assuming from page number is unique, if it is not unique then the ToPage number can be
    // used for comparison also.
    return (aFromPage < bFromPage) ? -1 : 1;
  })
});

// Handle the outer item
example.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
  if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(example));
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "id" : 3,
    "text" : "Another text",
    "pages":
        [
          "1-11",
          "12-34",
          "35-100"
        ]
  },
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "text" : "Some text",
    "pages":
        [
          "12-34",
          "35-44",
          "45-67",
          "68-100"
        ]
  }
]
```

Comment: @user3142695 I had a quick look at the updated post, unfortunately I don't have access to my comp anymore, *on mobile*. My example code should still work. Good luck and let me know how u went, will try to assist.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to sort element.

```
function transElement () {
  return parseInt(s.split('-')[0], 10);
}

elements.sort(function (a, b) {
  return transElement(b) - transElement(a);
});
```